# Unix 'grep' for a string within all gzip files in all subdirectories

Tags: unix, grep

How do I grep for a string recursively through all `.gz` files in all directories and subdirectories?

Answer (score 14):

@Steve Weet is almost there. The use of /dev/null as an additional argument is a nice way to force the filename to be shown (I'll remember that, thanks Steve) but it still runs the exec for every file found -- a huge overhead.

You want to run zgrep as few times as you can, getting the most out of each execution:

```
find . -iname '*.gz' -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep PATTERN
```

`xargs` will supply as many args (filenames) as possible to zgrep, and repeatedly execute it until it has used all the files supplied by the `find` command.  Using the `-print0` and `-0` options allows it to work if there are spaces in any of the file or directory names.

On Mac OS X, you can achieve the same effect without xargs:

```
find . -iname '*.gz' -exec zgrep PATTERN {} +
```

Comment: +1 That's really nice. I hadn't realised that xargs passed more than one argument. Much of my *nix command line-fu is 20 years old and I don't think xargs did that 20 years ago.

Comment: It turns out that find on os/x behaves the same way as xargs

Comment: See my comment to Steve Weet's answer regarding the '+' ending to -exec.

Comment: Use `-H` to always show the file name with the matching line, in GNU grep at least.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ zgrep --help
Usage: /bin/zgrep [OPTION]... [-e] PATTERN [FILE]...
Look for instances of PATTERN in the input FILEs, using their
uncompressed contents if they are compressed.
```

So something like

```
find . -iname "*.gz" -exec zgrep PATTERN {} \
```

Comment: The -exec will spawn a new instance of zgrep for every file it iterates over preventing you from seeing the file name. It would be better to use `zgrep -r` to go through a tree or if the -r doesn't work, pipe the output of the find through `xargs zgrep`

Comment: I get `/bin/zgrep: -r: option not supported` on my newly installed ubuntu system.

Comment: You can use `xargs` instead then.

Comment: See my comment to Steve Weet's answer regarding the '+' ending to -exec.

Answer (score 1):

@aioobe is almost there. The command will do the job but won't tell you the file name

The following should tell you the filename as well:

```
find . -iname "*.gz" -exec zgrep PATTERN {} /dev/null \;
```

The addition of `/dev/null` will ensure that zgrep sees two filenames so it will show you the name of the file if it finds the string

**EDIT**

Further research reveals that for my machine (OS/X) the `-exec` argument to find will add as many filenames as possible (similar to the way `xargs` behaves).

Comment: That's pretty cool, I didn't know that about the OSX `-exec` - I'm all about portability so I wouldn't use it in a script, but great for the command prompt.

Comment: For other versions of find, using '+' instead of '\;' to end the exec statement will do the same as OSX, by the stories in this thread, does by default. See the manual entry for '-exec command {} +'. It is not true of all versions of `find`, but most of the modern ones (e.g. in Debian based distros).

Comment: Use `-H` to always show the file name with the matching line, in GNU grep at least, instead of the `/dev/null` hack.

Answer (score 0):

The following works a treat in `zsh`

```
for archive in **/*.gz; do
    echo "[${archive}] "
    gzip -dc ${archive} | grep -n "String"
done
```

It may also work in `bash`, `ksh`, etc...